# DataTable bSortable columnDefs issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dt = $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "api.php?t=clients",
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
            'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [0]
        }],
            "columns": [{
            "className": "details-control",
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "   "
        }, {
            "data": "c_name"
        }, {
            "data": "c_number"
        }, {
            "data": "c_link"
        }]
    });
});
```

My code throw an error of SQL access violation when I included the following with

```
"aoColumnDefs": [ 
    { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0] } 
]
```

But if i remove it, everything works fine, basically I just want disable sorting for column 0

How do I achieve it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Change "aoColumnDefs" to "columnDefs"

```
"columnDefs": [{ 
     'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0]  
 }]
```

make sure you include these script files:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js